# Helpscreen that will only showup once - UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to show an `UIImage` with helpful tips when the user opens my app for the first time. I thought about putting a `UIImageView` and a button on top of the relevant `ViewController` and the image will be dismissed with a tap (alpha from 1 to 0) but I'm not sure that it's such a good idea to have a button and an `UIImageview` on top of my app at all times if it's only going to be used once. I want the image to be on top of the current ViewController so i can point to buttons etc' with arrows.
Is there a more elegant way accomplishing my goal?

And another thing, I want my app to remember that the picture was already shows. Should I use `NSUserDefaults` for that or is it there another solution I'm not aware of?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use NSUserDefaults.  Check this in the appDelegate and if not yet shown, show your image.  Forget alpha, just present a view controller (modally, popover, however you like) and include a "dismiss" or "close" button that dismisses the view controller.

Comment: I didn't mentioned it but I want the image to be on top of the current `ViewController` so i can point to buttons etc' with arrows. You still think alpha isn't the way to go?

Comment: It's definitely better to dismiss the view then it is to try and make it not visible. Then in subsequent runs you should just not show the view at all if it's already been shown. The memory associated with presenting a view is not insignificant even if it isn't visible to the user.

Comment: You should have a UIView with transparent background (alpha = 0) with the arrows and such as alpha = 1 as subviews, then present that view so it overlays the underlying view, then dismiss.

Comment: I used http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/kgmodal for this.  Still have to configure it how you want it but it provides a easy jump off point to display a quick modal view.